# Как реализовать свайп блока с помощью touchmove?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать плавное перетягивание пальцем блока `main` с помощью `touchmove`, зажимая `line`?

Начальное положение `main bottom = 0`, конечное положение `bottom = -300px;`.

Если по окончанию перетягивания значение `bottom` меньше (-100), то сразу присваивается значение (-300).

```js
const line = document.querySelector('.line')
const main = document.querySelector('.main')
line.addEventListener('touchmove', () => {

})
line.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
  if (parseInt(main.style.bottom) < (-100)) main.style.bottom = -300 + 'px'
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70vh;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
}

.line {
  width: 200px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50px;
  transition: opacity 600ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Попробуйте потащить</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так.
Если есть нюансы, прошу, подметить их.

```js
const line = document.querySelector('.line')
const main = document.querySelector('.main')
line.addEventListener('touchstart', (evt) => {
  main.style.removeProperty('transition');
  const firstTouch = evt.touches[0];
  y1 = firstTouch.clientY;
})

line.addEventListener('touchmove', (evt) => {
  const line = evt.target.querySelector('.line');
  if (!evt.target.closest('.line')) return;
  let y2 = evt.touches[0].clientY;
  let yDiff = y1 - y2;
  main.style.bottom = yDiff + 'px';
})

line.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
   main.style.transition = 'bottom 0.3s ease'
  if (parseInt(main.style.bottom) < (-150)) {
    main.style.bottom = -300 + 'px';
  } else {
    main.style.bottom = 0;
    }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70vh;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
}

.line {
  width: 200px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50px;
  transition: opacity 600ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Попробуйте потащить</p>
  </div>
</div>
```